# svn merge doesn't merge

Tags: svn, merge, trac

I'm trying to merge some hotfixes from trunk onto a branch. When I compare `trunk/foo.py` and `branches/feature/foo.py`, I see differences. Yet, when I run `svn merge https://<svn server>/trunk/foo.py foo.py`, no changes get merged. Retrying with the `--force` option has no effect either. It seems like SVN thinks that the feature branch's copy of `foo.py` is the latest version. How do I convince SVN otherwise?

**EDIT:** My Subversion client is `svn` version 1.6.16 (Linux). The server is running trac, version 0.12.

**EDIT2:** The version of subversion the server is 1.6.9. Thanks to hasienda in the comments for pointing out that trac and subversion aren't necessarily correlated.

Comment: What version of SVN? Looks like you're using a command line client?

Comment: I'm using SVN 1.6.16, and I'm using the command-line client for Linux.

Comment: In what way is this related to the Trac installation? Trac doesn't do anything to the repository other than making it accessible (read-only!) by the Trac repository browser via HTTP.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with trac, so I thought it somehow integrated Subversion. I've looked again and the subversion version on the server is 1.6.9.

Comment: Do you merge inside WC? WC of trunk or branch? Did you read `svn help merge`?

Comment: The merge was `server -> wc`, where `wc` is a copy of the branch. `svn help merge` and the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) both say that this should have been a straightforward affair - just another sync merge.

Comment: Does your working copy contain any local changes that have not yet been committed to your branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with;

- Are both the Trunk and Branch files committed to SVN? No merge can happen if the files aren't in the repository.
- Compare `svn info <trunk>/foo.py` and `svn <branch>/foo.py`; Check the last Changed Rev & Date, if SVN says they're the same file, no merge would happen.

You can check out [Advanced Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking) for additional information.

Comment: Thanks for the advanced merging link. I found that if I pointed SVN at the specific revision that I wanted merged, it'd merge. However, if I just told it to merge from the trunk's HEAD revision, it wouldn't merge. I'm going to have to take a look at this further in the future, but for now, I have the revisions, and I can continue working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of subversion you're using but merge tracking wasn't fully implemented until 1.5 I think.

Comment: My svn client is 1.6.16, according to `svn --version`. The server is actually trac, and it's version 0.12.

Comment: The actual version of subversion on the server is 1.6.9.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something in Subversion is behaving unexpectedly or seems to be harder than it should be, my general rule of thumb is to grab a fresh working copy in a new, clean directory and try it again with no local modifications.  This tends to rule out a number of subtle problems that can be hard to detect.

Also, do a `svn diff <server>/branches/this_branch <server>/trunk` to make sure Subversion thinks that there are changes to merge.  Using two repository paths here will eliminate any possible issues with your working copy.  If the above `diff` command gives you different results when you swap the branch URL with the path to your WC, then the problem is likely something in your working copy.

You can also do the merge purely in the repository by providing two full URLs to the `merge` command.  If you go that route, I highly suggest using the `--dry-run` option to preview the merge before making it official.

Also, is there a reason why you are merging using specific filenames and not simply merging the the entire `/trunk` to your branch?  I typically see far fewer problems when merging entire revisions into a branch rather than into specific files.